# DataError: Malformed array literal when inserting multidimensional array into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

This is a simplified version of my table:

```
class Alert(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'alert'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_on = Column(DateTime(timezone=True))
    category = Column(Unicode, nullable=False)
    parameters = Column(ARRAY(Unicode), nullable=True)
```

When trying to insert the following multidimensional array into the table, I get a DataError telling me that my array is malformed.

```
DataError: (DataError) malformed array literal: "numbers"
LINE 1: ...RRAY[ARRAY['key', 'sXl5SoNh0KY'], ARRAY['nu...
                                                   ^
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
'INSERT INTO alert (created_on, category, parameters) 
VALUES (%(created_on)s, %(category)s, %(parameters)s) 
RETURNING alert.id' {
'created_on': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 24, 1, 52, 30, 631330, tzinfo=<UTC>)
'category': u'new_cases',
'parameters':
    [[u'key', u'sXl5SoNh0KY'],
    ['numbers', [u'8129431', u'8669290', u'8754131', u'8871813', u'8927606']],
    ['status', 'all']]
}
```

I was under the impression that Postgres' ARRAY type is multidimensional  regardless of how it is created (http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.sqlalchemy.user/31186), so why is this error occurring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays in PostgreSQL can be multidimensional, but all the elements *must* have the same number of dimensions (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/arrays.html), so you can write:

```
SELECT ARRAY[ARRAY[1,2], ARRAY[3,4]];

=> "{{1,2},{3,4}}"
```

but not:

```
SELECT ARRAY[ARRAY[1,2], ARRAY[3]]

ERROR:  multidimensional arrays must have array expressions with matching dimensions
```