# Python to parse html data and store into the database

Tags: python, html, postgresql, insert, beautifulsoup

a
This is trouble me for two days, I am new one to python, I want to Parse the html data as the following link:http://movie.walkerplus.com/list/2015/12/

and then store the data into the postgresql database named movie_db, and there is table named films which is created by the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE films (
title       varchar(128) NOT NULL,
description varchar(256) NOT NULL,
directors   varchar(128)[],
roles       varchar(128)[]
);
```

I have parsed data, there are three list data for title, description, director, roles. such as title =['a', .....,'b'], description = ['c',....,'f'], director= ['d',.....,'g'], roles = [['f','g','t'], ......,['h', 't','u']].

sql = "INSERT INTO films (title, description, directors, roles)
      VALUES
      (%s, %s, %s, %s);"
     for obj in zip(t, des, dirt, r):
     cur.execute(cur.mogrify(sql, obj))
     conn.commit()

There is error:

```
 psycopg2.DataError: malformed array literal: "サム・メンデス"

LINE 1: ...ームズ・ボンドの戦いを描く『007』シリーズ第24作', 'サム・メ...
                                                         ^
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

Comment: Hi, if you want to get more information, please tell me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataError: Malformed array literal when inserting multidimensional array into PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31016528/dataerror-malformed-array-literal-when-inserting-multidimensional-array-into-po)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this error. It means you are trying to insert string values into array columns. You can verify the SQL as below.

```
sql2 = cur.mogrify(SQL, obj)
print sql2
```

Your directors and roles fetched from html are list of strings. So after zip function the obj contains dir and roles as strings.

For your case you are trying to insert only 1 row. So there is probably no need to zip.

I am not familiar with this API you used, but can you try to print the values received from html before inserting? I can provide you the exact SQL required.

**Edit** About the syntax for the new array

the directors array is a shorthand syntax to create a new array with each element as array. In a more readable syntax, it will be same as below

```
director = ['tom', 'jack', 'john']
directors = []

for d in director:
    elem_as_list = []
    elem_as_list.append(d)
    directors.append(elem_as_list)
print director
print directors
print type(director[0])
print type(directors[0])
```

Here is the output

```
['tom', 'jack', 'john']
[['tom'], ['jack'], ['john']]
<type 'str'>
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: Thanks@Gouri， I have solved this issue. because I forgot to dict = [[d, ]] for d in dirt]. Thanks for your advice, you are a good guy.

Comment: @KeTian, I am glad I could help you.