# python: insert the list data into database

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, list, insert

there is postgresql database named movie_db, and created a table named films as following:

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
 title       varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 description varchar(256) NOT NULL,
 directors   varchar(128)[],
 roles       varchar(128)[]
 );
```

I have four list for the title, description, directors, roles.
for example(maybe a large list not just three elements).

```
title = ['a', 'b', 'c']
description = ['good love', 'sun beautiful', 'wind go']
director = ['tom', 'jack', 'john']
roles=[['kate', 'back', 'jon'], ['tian', 'den', 'lucy'], ['cruse', 'jodan', 'peter']]
```

I want to insert these list data into the table films, How could I use the python sql to deal with it, I want to get the result like the following table, please notice that the roles not just has one name, sometimes have three names, such as kate, back, jon

```
 title          description    director       roles

  a               good love      tom        kate, back, jon    
  b               sun beautiful  jack       tian,  den,  lucy
  c               wind go        john       cruse, jodan, peter
```

I use the following python code:

```
 cur.execute('insert into film_test(title, description, directors, 
 roles)values(%s, %s, %s, %s)', title, description, director, roles)
```

But there is error:

```
 TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (5 given)
```

Could you use the python to insert into the table, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**psycopg2** has a great support for array insert. This probably will help.

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="postgres")
cur = conn.cursor()

title = ['a', 'b', 'c']
description = ['good love', 'sun beautiful', 'wind go']
director = ['tom', 'jack', 'john']
directors = [ [d, ] for d in director ]
roles=[['kate', 'back', 'jon'], ['tian', 'den', 'lucy'], ['cruse', 'jodan', 'peter']]

sql = "INSERT INTO movies (title, description, directors, roles) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);"
for obj in zip(title, description, directors, roles):
    cur.execute(cur.mogrify(sql, obj))
conn.commit()

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: BTW, I created the directors list to change individual elements to list type.(in accordance with your database column definition).

Comment: I really thanks for your help, I will report my result!

Comment: Thanks!@ Nouri, when use your code or method to insert the html data which parsed by the python, I found there is error, please see this question link(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37566197/python-parse-html-data-and-store-into-the-postgresql-database):

Comment: Thanks@Gouri, it works! Could you explain this code meaning: directors = [ [d, ] for d in director ], and why the roles did not need this? Thanks, you are a good guy.